# Progressively change all images on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have a client who asked to temporarily hide all images on a webpage, but without creating a 404 (leaving them visible to bots).

My try was this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("img").attr({src: "/my/path/myfile.png"});
});
```

The problem is that on a slow connection, images are loading, and only on `$(document).ready()` are hiding (of course - that is what I asked in the code :-) - I do not know a different method …)

How can I make it so that all the images will be "*hidden*" on browser side, while loading, in a progressive way?

Comment: So what you're *really* trying to do is show a placeholder image while an image is loading?

Comment: @Blender - It is actually the same for me . the code I used was pointing to a non existing path ... but actually I need to HIDE .

Comment: @Blender - (after editing comment ) - no. I want the images to NOT be visible to the client browser , not even for a fraction of a second - and on the same time not produce 404 for bots.

Comment: So what does the "*, while loading , in a progressive way ?*" part mean then?

Comment: @Blender Meaning that I want the images to hide one by one while loading , and not all of them at the same time after doc is ready ..

Comment: Note that if you have different content for bots and actual users you might get kicked out of search engines if they find out.

Comment: @Juhana - I know, and so does the client. This is why I wrote " temporarily" . It is only for about 10 hours , for a specific business meeting he has . But thanks for the advice .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply hide them using CSS:

```
img {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

This way all images are linked correctly, your content flow is intact (in contrary of using `display: none;`), you don't need any JavaScript and the users won't see them.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/tZfmF/)

Comment: Why ?? Because I was too tired to think of it myself !! :- ) But won´t it create also layout problems ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZfmF/). Using this CSS rule your content flow is still the same as before.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to shoot a fly with a canon. But I think I actually will use the combination of both methods. Some clients have odd requests. I wonder why people voting this down.. Is that because of being bots advocates here ? :-)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen You might run into some issues if you combine both things, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/UGGDN/). The layout will only be kept, if all images have set their widths and heights explicitly or you link to an actual placeholder image with the same dimensions.

Comment: It would be nice , just for the scope of learning (and even if the answer is already accepted ) to see if and how this can be done with jQuery ( regardless of css )

Comment: On my browser also the second demo keeps the layout , and so is the actuall page of the client . since it is only for about 10 hours, I guess it is ok anyhow .. but maybe indeed it is browser dependent . ( checked with firefox 16, chrome on win7)

Comment: Really? Maybe it's only Safari. Didn't test anywhere else. ;)

Comment: Using jQuery you could of course do: [`$('img').css('visibility', 'hidden');`](http://jsfiddle.net/8A6Hb/). ;) But you will again have the flash of the already loaded images.

Comment: thanks . My question was aimed more at understanding how to target something with jQuery in a "progressive" way while loading (element per element) as opposed to document.ready . But hey - it works for now :-) thanks a bunch again ..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen You can remove the `.ready()`-function, if you place everything at the [bottom of the page](http://jsfiddle.net/3mquR/). If you want to do it right after each element, you have to place a short script after each single `<img`>-tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways that I know to do this.

```
img {
  background: url('loading.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

and

```
<script>
$('#loadImg').show();
$('#BaseImage').load(function(){$('#loadImg').hide();});
</script>
```

You assign load event to the image which fires when image has finished loading but background image to all images using css will be easier. Take note that This doesn't work very well with transparent images.